# $\frac{dz}{dx}$ term explanation for $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 +6xyz = 1$

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation, differential

I know that the full answer is $$3x^2 + 3z^2 \cdot \frac{dz}{dx} +6yz + (6xy \cdot \frac{dz}{dx})$$ but where does the final part in brackets come from?

I know how to solve the rest, but an explanation of the final term would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you have assumed that $$z=z(x)$$

Comment: Could you show us the original question please. Also, please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

We have that assuming $y$ constant

$$x^3 + y^3 + z^3 +6xyz = 1 \implies 3x^2dx+3z^2dz+6yzdx\color{red}{+6xydz}=0$$

that is dividing by $dx$

$$3x^2+3z^2\frac{dz}{dx}+6yz\color{red}{+6xy\frac{dz}{dx}}=0\implies \frac{dz}{dx}=-\frac{3x^2+6yz}{3z^2dz+6xy}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is the chain rule, and we get
$$3x^2+3z^2z'(x)+6yz+6xyz'(x)=0$$